# Getting "Unexpected token" error in my main.js

Tags: javascript

My script and web application keeps failing because of an error I am getting in the console info:

```
main.js:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')';
```

This is my script:

```
$(function () {
    var client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
    showInfo();
    showError();
    client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
        function (data) {
            var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
            console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
  )
}});
function showInfo() {
    var requester_data = {
        'name': 'Jane Doe',
        'tags': ('tag1', 'tag2'),
        'created_at': 'November 20, 2014',
        'last_login_at': 'June 27, 2016'
    };

    var source = $("#requester-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(requester_data);
    $("#content").html(html);
}
function showError() {
    var error_data = {
        'status': 404,
        'statusText': 'Not found'
    };
    var source = $("#error-template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var html = template(error_data);
    $("#content").html(html);
}
```

I changed the code to this:

```
$(function() {
  var client = ZAFClient.init();
  client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
  showInfo();
  showError();
  client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
    function(data) {
      var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
      console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
});
function showInfo() {
  var requester_data = {
    'name': 'Jane Doe',
    'tags': ('tag1', 'tag2'),
    'created_at': 'November 20, 2014',
    'last_login_at': 'June 27, 2016'
  };

  var source = $("#requester-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(requester_data);
  $("#content").html(html);
}
function showError() {
  var error_data = {
    'status': 404,
    'statusText': 'Not found'
  };
  var source = $("#error-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html = template(error_data);
  $("#content").html(html);
}
```

And now I get this console error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at main.js:1.
```

That sign wasn't the problem before so I don't know why now it became the problem when I changed the code.

So far I have been struggling because I am new with JavaScript and don't have good hang of it.

Comment: "an error I am getting in console info" — Is there a reason you are keeping the error message secret from us?

Comment: Sorry no reason just forgot, main.js:10 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'; It says it's in 10th row which are brackets but I don't get what is wrong with them.

Comment: You have a typo. You have a `)` but there is no `(` to match it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing correctly your function here :

```
client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
  function(data) {
    var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
    console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
)}});
```

should be replaced by :

```
client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
    function(data) {
      var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
      console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

As HRK44 and Quentin have pointed out, you have left one extra `)` that is not matched in your code. You wil be able to easily identify such errors if you use a text editor intended for writing code (such as sublime and VS code) which tend to include syntax highlighting to preemptively identify such syntax errors.

To fix your current error you can change -

```
$(function () {
    var client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
    showInfo();
    showError();
    client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
        function (data) {
            var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
            console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
  )
}});
```

to

```
$(function () {
    var client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
    showInfo();
    showError();
    client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
        function (data) {
            var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
            console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: You have just misplaced brackets. 
No.of closing brackets are correct.

```
client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
    function (data) {
        var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
        console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
    }
)
```

Just correct last two brackets as shown.

```
$(function () {
    var client = ZAFClient.init();
    client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
    showInfo();
    showError();
    client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
        function (data) {
            var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
            console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this usefull**

```
$(function() {
  var client = ZAFClient.init();
  client.invoke('resize', { width: '150%', height: '120px' });
  showInfo();
  showError();
  client.get('ticket.requester.id').then(
    function(data) {
          var user_id = data['ticket.requester.id'];
          console.log('Requester id is ' + user_id);
    }
  );
}); // you didnt closed it properly
```